# Resource files in the dependency project are not copied to the main spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, configuration

I have two maven spring boot projects.

1. jwt-auth(dependency project)
2. ws-main(main project)

The jwt-auth project has been added as a dependency to a main project and finally build the main project as an executable jar. Each project has its own configuration and is stored in a resource folder.

**jwt-auth project**

[image]

**ws-main project**

[image]

So, my problem is after building the executable jar, configuration files in the dependency project are not copied to the main project's classpath. because of that some settings that are configured in application.properties and logback.xml in jwt-auth project are not working.

*For ex:- the application.properties file in jwt-auth project does not copy to the main project classpath and because of that, I have to copy all the properties in the dependency project to the main project application.properties file before building the main project.*

So, I need to know if is this possible and if possible how can I configure both projects without missing any configuration file in the final build.

**jwt-auth project's pom file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dakd.ws.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwt-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JWT Authentication</name>
    <description>Handle JWT authentication</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <lombok-maven-plugin>1.18.26</lombok-maven-plugin>
        <jjwt-maven-plugin>0.11.5</jjwt-maven-plugin>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-maven-plugin}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-maven-plugin}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-maven-plugin}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt-maven-plugin}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.dakd.ws.auth.jwt.JwtAuthenticationApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ws-main project's pom file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dakd.ws.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws-main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ws-main</name>
    <description>Handle basic authentication</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dakd.ws.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwt-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ws-main</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>repackage</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>ws-main</finalName>
                    <!--<finalName>tax-customer-ws-${build.profile.id}</finalName>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main class you can add this annotation for custom properties.

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties","file:${MY_PATH}/application.properties"})
```

I am not sure, but you can probably change properties file name in your jar and pass like this

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties","classpath:jar-application.properties"})
```